# Как выполнять pipeline на нужном stage?

Tags: jenkins

Есть pipeline c параметром выбора stage1/stage2 (Webtarget).
На ум приходит только конструкция if при выборе нужного сервера.

Params:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Pipeline:

```html
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Running 'php-fpm bin/console c:c;' ") {
            steps {
                sh "ssh -tt -hostname@ip 'cd /var/www/staging_1 && docker-compose exec php-fpm bin/console c:c' "
            }
        }
        stage("Running 'php-fpm bin/console d:c:clear-m' ") {
            steps {
                sh "ssh -tt hostname@ip 'cd /var/www/staging_1 && docker-compose exec php-fpm bin/console d:c:clear-m' "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**if ("${params.Webtarget}" == "stage1")**

Есть ли какие-то еще способы, а то будет слишком длинный pipeline ибо тестовых серверов штук 10.
Спасибо

Comment: не совсем ясно, что **именно** вас не устраивает (приведите, пожалуйста, пример вашего описания pipeline. прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]). да и сама постановка вопроса «как выполнять pipeline на нужном stage», честно говоря, вбивает в ступор. плюс ещё непонятно к чему упомянуты «штук 10 серверов». что бы это значило? «условное выполнение stage»? «условный выбор сервера для выполнения stage»? ещё что-то?

Answer (score 0):

если вопрос всё-таки касается не «десяти серверов», а условного выполнения стадий (*stages*), то можно воспользоваться директивой [`when`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when):

```
stage ( ... ) {
  when { условие }
  ...
}
```

если `условие` вернёт `false`, то не будет выполнена ни одна из директив внутри данной стадии.

условий может быть и несколько. тогда их надо либо поместить в отдельные строки, либо разделить символом `;`. чтобы стадия выполнилась, все они должны вернуть `true`.

---

пара примеров для иллюстрации:

```
stage ('стадия1') {
  when { environment name: 'Webtarget', value: 'stage1' }
  ...
}
stage ('стадия2') {
  when { expression { return params.Webtarget == 'stage2' } }
  ...
}
```